# change a word in a matching line

Tags: regex, linux, unix, awk, sed

I try to search and replace a word but only in lines containing a pattern. For my case it's a /etc/fstab file and I would like to modify ro flag to rw but only for some specific share.

This is how my NFS shares look like:

```
servername1:/path/to/share1 /nfs/mount1 nfs ro,nosuid,soft,vers=3   0 0
servername2:/path/to/share1 /nfs/mount2 nfs ro,nosuid,soft,vers=3   0 0
servername1:/path/to/share2 /nfs/mount3 nfs ro,nosuid,soft,vers=3   0 0
```

I want to change this to:
    servername1:/path/to/share1 /nfs/mount nfs rw,nosuid,soft,vers=3    0 0

But only for a specific server and share. I tried this:

```
sed '/servername1.*share1 s/ro/rw' fstab
```

But it didn't work. So which regex should I use in order to accomplish my goal?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `sed`:

```
sed '/^servername1.*share1/s/ro,/rw,/' fstab
```

**Output:**

```
servername1:/path/to/share1 /nfs/mount1 nfs rw,nosuid,soft,vers=3 0 0
servername2:/path/to/share1 /nfs/mount2 nfs ro,nosuid,soft,vers=3 0 0
servername1:/path/to/share2 /nfs/mount3 nfs ro,nosuid,soft,vers=3 0 0
```

Comment: this will modify both share1 and share2 from servername1 right? I just want to modify share1 from servername1 not  share2